# How to pivot a dataframe correctly without losing any data?

Tags: python, pivot-table, data-transform

I have a following DataFrame:

| model | metric | final_result | score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Decision Tree | F1 | Pass | 0.57346 |
| Decision Tree | accuracy | Pass | 0.76512 |
| Decision Tree | precision | Pass | 0.6346 |
| Decision Tree | recall | Pass | 0.66512 |
| Decision Tree | F1 | Fail | 0.57346 |
| Decision Tree | accuracy | Fail | 0.76512 |
| Decision Tree | precision | Fail | 0.6346 |
| Decision Tree | recall | Fail | 0.66512 |
| RF | F1 | Pass | 0.57346 |
| RF | accuracy | Pass | 0.76512 |
| RF | precision | Pass | 0.6346 |
| RF | recall | Pass | 0.66512 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

I want to pivot the table to the following format:

|  |  | Decision Tree | Random Forest |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **final_result** | **metric** |  |  |
| Pass | accuracy | 0.76512 | 0.76512 |
|  | precision | 0.6346 | 0.6346 |
|  | recall | 0.66512 | 0.66512 |
|  | F1 | 0.57436 | 0.57346 |
| Fail | accuracy | 0.76512 | 0.76512 |
|  | precision | 0.6346 | 0.6346 |
|  | recall | 0.66512 | 0.66512 |
|  | F1 | 0.57436 | 0.57346 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

I tried doing this by using the `pivot_table` function like this:

```
pd.pivot_table(modelPerformance, values='score', index=['metric', 'Final Result'], columns='model')
```

However, that leaves me with a "squashed" table that looks like this:
[image]

I'm stumped because it's hard to explain this issue and find possible solutions online, so I'm hoping someone here will understand my end goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, use `pivot` instead of `pivot_table`:

```
>>> df.pivot(['final_result', 'metric'], 'model', 'score')

model                   Decision Tree       RF
final_result metric                           
Fail         F1               0.57346      NaN
             accuracy         0.76512      NaN
             precision        0.63460      NaN
             recall           0.66512      NaN
Pass         F1               0.57346  0.57346
             accuracy         0.76512  0.76512
             precision        0.63460  0.63460
             recall           0.66512  0.66512
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I tried the aforementioned approach already (using pivot) but I get the following error `Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape`.

Comment: When you have duplicate values for a same index/column (cell), what do you want to do? Compute the mean, get the first or the last value, other?

Comment: In fact, I think you don't want to aggregate values because you don't want 'losing any data'

Comment: I think my issue is in the data itself, I'd like to keep the first value I suppose.